# Synchronizing scrolling in two side-by-side trees in JFace

Tags: synchronization, scrollbar, jface

I'm looking to synchronize two `TreeViewer`s in JFace.

The first step I suppose is understanding exactly what is making the scroll bars appear in the first place. When I look at the [TreeViewer API](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TreeViewer.html) I don't see any mention of ScrollBar or anything that subclasses or implements it.

What is defining them and making them appear in my TreeViewer (when I shrink the size of the window)?

And then, how do I synchronize the scrolling across two trees?

Comment: I spent quite some time trying to sync two tables (they are very similar to trees) - it does not seem possible on all platforms (I had a fairly ok GTK version that was completely broken on Mac. And I did not even try Windows...

Comment: @Eugene Can you give me a lead?

Comment: I was trying to use this: http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet234.java. The issue I faced is that table can only be scrolled to the whole item - e.g. you won't get smooth scroll with the pixel precision. I dried going deeper (e.g. to use underlying GTK+ and Cocoa) - it kinda worked but I abandoned the project as I don't know Win32 and didn't want to dive there while our product is also available there.

Comment: @Eugene thanks for letting me know - however that is not a problem for me. I will check out what you've suggested...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to add a **SelectionListener** to the VerticalScroll bar on both, left and right, TreeViewer's tree.

```
leftTreeViewer.getTree().getVerticalBar().addSelectionListener(this);
rightTreeViewer.getTree().getVerticalBar().addSelectionListener(this);
```

Then on your widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)

```
@Override
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource().equals(rightTreeViewer.getTree().getVerticalBar())){
        onTreeVerticalScrollSelected(rightTreeViewer, leftTreeViewer);
    }else if(e.getSource().equals(leftTreeViewer.getTree().getVerticalBar())){
        onTreeVerticalScrollSelected(leftTreeViewer, rightTreeViewer);
    }
}

private void onTreeVerticalScrollSelected(TreeViewer target, TreeViewer other){
    other.getTree().getVerticalBar().setSelection(target.getTree().getVerticalBar().getSelection());
}
```

This is working for me quite smoothly on linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SWT "frozen column" [snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet234.java) - apparently, this is as close as you can get to scroll position synchronization with SWT that works on all platforms.

Note that SWT can only scroll programmatically to a table item so you may not be able to implement smooth scroll synchronization.

The scrollbars are managed by underlying native tree widget. You can try either forcing or disabling the scrollbars by passing style bits to your widget constructor - SWT.NO_SCROLL should disable the scrollbars, SWT.H_SCROLL and SWT.V_SCROLL should always show corresponding scrollbars. Note that these flags are only hints - native implementation may ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this:

```
((Tree) yourTreeView.getControl()).getHorizontalBar().setValue(...);
```